# Mean Absolute Deviation for AR(1) process

Tags: autoregressive, mean-absolute-deviation

Is there closed-form solution for mean absolute deviation (MAD) for AR(1) process?

$X_t = c + \beta X_{t-1} + \epsilon_t $

$\epsilon_t \sim N(0,\sigma^{\epsilon})$

(Similar to the variance and the mean for AR(1): as we can derive mean as $\frac{c}{1-\beta}$ and variance as $\frac{\sigma_t^{epsilon}}{1-\beta}$.)

But for MAD how to proceed from this? Or there's no closed-form solution?

$$MAD = |X_t - E[X_t]| = |c + \beta X_{t-1} + \epsilon_t - \mu|,$$

where $\mu = E[X_t]$.

Comment: Certainly not, because you make so few assumptions about $\epsilon_t.$  Did you mean to suppose these terms have Normal distributions?